# Setting up flask test_client

Tags: unit-testing, flask

I am trying to test my flask app but I am getting this error

> RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.
>   This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
>   to interface with the current application object in a way.  To solve
>   this set up an application context with app.app_context().  See the
>   documentation for more information.`

I have tried understanding the error but all I kknow is that there is a client instance that should be instantiated to be used in testing. Help. 
My code:

```
import unittest

from flask import jsonify


class TestAuth(unittest.TestCase):
"""Class for testing all the API endpoints"""
def setUp(self):
    """Initializing a test client and making the environment a testing one"""
    app.app.config['TESTING'] = True
    self.app = app.app.test_client()
    self.app.testing = True

def sign_in(self, email='user@gmail.com', password='testpass'):
    user_data = jsonify({"email": email, "password": password})
    return self.app.post('/api/v1/auth/signup/', data=user_data)

def log_in(self, email='user@gmail.com', password='testpass'):
    user_data = jsonify({"email": email, "password": password})
    return self.app.post('/api/v1/auth/login/', data=user_data)

def test_home_status_code(self):

    result = self.app.get('/api/v1/')
    self.assertEqual(result.status_code, 200)

def test_signin_status_code(self):
    result = self.sign_in()
    self.assertEqual(result.status_code, 200)

def test_login_correct_login(self):
    """test login after signing in"""
    self.sign_in()
    result = self.log_in()
    self.assertEqual(result.status_code, 200)
    self.assertIn(b'Success', result.message)

def test_login_with_wrong_credentials(self):
    """test successful login"""
    self.sign_in()  # must sign in first for successful login
    result = self.log_in(email='wrong@mail', password='wrongpass')
    self.assertIn(b'Wrong Username or Password', result.message)


if __name__ == "__main__":
unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def test_home_status_code(self):

    with self.app as client:
        result = client.get('/api/v1/')
        self.assertEqual(result.status_code, 200)
```